# AspectJ in back-end Java thread with POM based weaving

Tags: multithreading, aop, aspectj, java-threads, mbeans

I have a back-end thread, which I created inside start method of JBoss Mbeans:

```java
public interface HScannerServiceMBean {
  public void create();
  public void start();
  public void stop();
  public void destroy();
  public boolean isMasterNode();
  public void startSingleton(); 
  public void stopSingleton();
}
```

```java
public class HScannerService implements HScannerServiceMBean {
  public void create() {
    log.info("Creating Service.......................................");
  }

  public void start() {
    log.info("Starting Service.......................................");
    TestThread tt;
    try {
      tt = new TestThread(1);
      tt.startThread();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

```java
public class TestThread implements Runnable {
  private boolean running = false;
  int mThreadName;

  private Thread thread;

  protected TestThread(int pThreadName) throws NamingException {
    mThreadName = pThreadName;
    this.thread = new Thread(this);
    this.thread.setDaemon(true);
    this.thread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
  }

  public void startThread() {
    if (!this.running) {
      this.running = true;
      this.thread.start();
    } else {
      log.info("Thread already running");
    }
  }

  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Thread run method");
    throw new NumberFormatException("incorrect number");
  }

  public void terminate() {
    setRunning(false);
  }

  public boolean isRunning() {
    return running;
  }

  public void setRunning(boolean running) {
    this.running = running;
  }
}
```

I have added AspectJ in the pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>
```

My aspect class looks like this:

```java
@Aspect
public class ExceptionTranslationAspect {
  @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.ent.service..*(..)) || execution(* com.ent.domain..*(..))", throwing = "ex")
  public void logAfterThrowingExceptionCall(Exception ex) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("****exception received!");
  }
}
```

The thread is throwing a simple exception, which should be caught by this aspect and print "****exception received!". But the aspect method is not getting called. My question is, can we use AspectJ with back-end threads? If yes, what is the problem with my code?

I am using JDK 8 and Wildfly 16.

Comment: Hi Imran. Please note how I reformatted your question to make it more readable. You may click "edit" and see what the markdown code looks like now and then next time do it in a similar way. Just give your questions a bit more love and care in the future, please. Thank you so much. Please also note that the name is AspectJ, not Aspect4J. I also fixed that in several places.

Comment: Closed as duplicate. In the linked answer, look for the Maven Surefire configuration to see how `-javaagent` is used there. Please also note that you need a properly configured _aop.xml_. If all of this is too complicated for you, then maybe compile-time weaving would be easier. I am unsure how dynamic your solution needs to be, which is why I suggested LTW at first. Without a complete reproducer, I cannot say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Adding AspectJ libraries to your POM will not activate AspectJ. You either need to use load-time weaving by means of `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectweaver.jar` or by another means of configuring your agent in WildFly, if there is any. Or you can use compile-time weaving, utilising AspectJ Maven Plugin.

Besides, specifying two conflicting versions of AspectJ in the same POM is not helping either. I recommend to simply use the latest release AspectJ 1.9.20.1.

Comment: you can I have used that in POM. How to set it as java agent?

Comment: I do not understand what you just wrote.

Comment: you can see I have that weaver in my POM.xml. Is there anything else I need to do to use that weaver? How to set it as java agent

Comment: I already told you in my answer how to use it. Please read more carefully. If you need any other basic information about how to use AspectJ load-time weaving, I recommend to use a search engine and learn the basics. Then, if you have tried and experience specific problems, feel free to ask another question, including an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I think, this one I have answered correctly already.

Comment: then it's not a very useful answer, if I have to use that much search engine and filtering my requirement. Also the javaagent that you have set was not related to my answer. I fixed this by adding in POM.xml. I think you should also search how you can use load time weaving by just using the same POM

Comment: On the contrary: The Java agent is exactly related to your answer, if you want to use load-time weaving. Besides, you would not have to "use that much search engine", but a simple search will yield useful results on page 1. Or maybe start with the [AspectJ manual chapter on LTW](https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw-configuration.html). Even here on Stack Overflow, you would find answers. I am, however, still unsure what your question really is.

Comment: Your POM describes a build configuration. LTW is used when running the program you just built. So the POM might not be the place where you want to use `-javaagent`, unless of course you run your program during the build, e.g. in Surefire for automated tests. I am assuming that this is what you want to do and will close this question as a duplicate of a similar question.

Comment: And thank you so much for your downvote, just because you do not like my answer and are too lazy to also contribute to your own success a little bit by reading documentation.  This sense of entitlement is what keeps people from answering questions of users like you. Did you notice that I was the only one trying to help you despite your unclear question? I think I should have invested my time into helping someone else instead.

Comment: I created question after struggling a lot. You said you don't understand the question, is that mean I am lazy? I downvoted because instead of providing the answer or asking for more explanation you guys here demotivate people asking questions.  I don't know who you are, Why would I downvote without any reason?
I am not using any kind of Surefire or any testing. Just added weaving in POM and it worked.

Comment: Of course, I a not calling you lazy for asking a question after struggling to find your own answer. That is what Stack Overflow is designed for: To ask questions and get stright answers. The "lazy" part is about you being unwilling to take my correct answer and find out how to use the `-javaagent` JVM argument as an input for Google or read the AspectJ manual chapter I liked to. Explaining the basics of how to use a Java agent in general or repeating whole manual chapters really is beyond the scope on an answer here.

Comment: The "lazy" term also applies to you being unwilling to share a full reproducer or add sufficient detail to your question for meto answer it directly and precisely, but forcing me to speculate what your situation might be like. Just lookt at the sheer amount of comments here. Normally, it should be simply question and answer, maybe one or two comments. SO is not a discussion forum.

Comment: You don't know who I am, you said. That is fine. Why would you need to know me? I am just a community member trying to support you. But as you were wondering, I might as well mention that I happen to be the current maintainer of AspectJ. So, if I do not understand your question, chances are that nobody else does either.

Comment: Finally, what is "just added weaving and it worked" supposed to mean? Again, your statement is unclear. There are at least 3 types of weaving: compile time, post-compile time and load time. As your question was unclear, I suggested load time, but also mentioned that if you control the woven source code and it happens to be Java, compile time is also an option. I even mentioned AspectJ Maven Plugin for that purpose. You did not respond to that in any meaningful way, but downvoted my answer were surprised that I complained about that. My answer is correct, you simply did not follow my pointers.

Comment: instead of typing so many comments afterward, next time try to be more clear in your answer. thanks

Comment: How can you be so cheeky? My comments were not written to explain the answer but pure meta comments, because you have this sense of entitlement, refusing to read any basic documentation as recommended, and expecting a different answer, because your question is unclear. My answer is clear and concise, you simply did not read it carefully. Besides, you did not explain how you allegedly made your own solution work. Users like you spoil life on this platform for ones like me who have literally witten hundreds of answers and dedicate their sparse sparetime to helping others.

Comment: next time, try to be REALLY helpful

Comment: Next time, try to write a comprehensive question with a complete, minimal, reproducible example. Besides, for people like you I do not waste my energy and goodwill for a "next time". I do like to help fellow developers here, but not if they react like you did.